# Normalizer null reference using NormalizerAwareTrait

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, symfony-3.2

I have two `objects` with a `Parent`-`Child` relationship. For each `object` I have a custom `normalizer` as can be seen below:

#### ChildNormalizer.php

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\scalar;

class ChildNormalizer
{  
    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = array())
    {
      return [
        "name" => $object->getName(),
        "age" => $object->getAge(),
        ...
        ];
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return ($data instanceof Child) && is_object($data);
    }
}
```

#### ParentNormalizer.php

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\NormalizationAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerAwareTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\scalar;

class ParentNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface, NormalizationAwareInterface
{
    use NormalizerAwareTrait;

    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = array())
    {
      return [
        ...
        "children" => array_map(
            function ($child) use ($format, $context) {
                return $this->normalizer->normalize($child);
            }, $object->getChildren()
          ),
        ...
        ];
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return ($data instanceof Parent) && is_object($data);
    }
}
```

When I try to serialize the `Parent` `object` which in turn normalizes the `Child` `object` I get the following exception:

> ```
> Call to a member function normalize() on null
> ```

Have I missed a configuration step, or what the hell am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved the issue, I was implementing the wrong `*AwareInterface`.

The code works perfectly if the `ParentNormalizer` implements `NormalizerAwareInterface` rather than `NormalizationAwareInterface`.

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\NormalizerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerAwareTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\scalar;

class ParentNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface, NormalizerAwareInterface
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Thanks for posting the solution! It's an easy mistake to make.

Comment: Thank you! *facepalm* :D